# Password reader String Array

Tags: c, strcmp, gets, do-loops

So my program is designed to great the user and ask for a password. once the user enters a password it is compared to my precoded password "ans[]" and if the password matches what the user enters then it prints a welcome greeting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
char hello[] = "Hello! \nPassword Required:";
char password[50];
char ans[] = "Zanderg!";

printf(hello);
printf("\n");
gets(password);

if (strcmp(password, ans) != 0) {
    do {
    printf("%s Not correct.\n", password);
    printf("Enter Password:\n");
    gets(password);
    getchar();
    }while (strcmp(password, ans) != 0);
};

if (strcmp(password, ans) == 0) {
    printf("welcome %s", password);
}
}
```

My issue is that When i enter the right password i still get a "wrong password" message.

Im also getting this really weird message about how gets() is unsafe and i'm wondering if i have any alternatives to gets() or how i can get rid of this error message in my program. My compiler is Xcode.

Comment: your program worked on my system(gcc). Which compiler you are using?

Comment: ya it worked one time and hasnt works since...i havnet changed anythign so im not sure what the problem is. I'm using Xcode @SGG

Comment: Nevermind...i found the problem. @SGG

Comment: + semicolon after if statement is not needed

Comment: @Zanderg what is the problem?

Comment: `gets(password);` --> `scanf(" %49[^\n]", password);`

Comment: Just a Stupid input Error. I managed to enter an ! into my ans[]=Zanderg! so when i was typing in my password it wasnt correct cause i was only typing Zanderg. @SGG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zanderg said that he found the problem, but he never bothered to mention what it was. I'll go ahead and post it regardless for anybody who might still be interested.

Let's try the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char password[50];
    char ans[] = "Zanderg!";

    printf("Hello! \nPassword Required:\n");
    fgets(password, sizeof(ans),stdin);

    if (strcmp(password, ans) != 0) {
        do {
        printf("%s Not correct.\n", password);
        printf("Enter Password:\n");
        fgets(password, sizeof(ans),stdin);
        getchar();
        }while (strcmp(password, ans) != 0);
    };

    if (strcmp(password, ans) == 0) {
        printf("welcome %s", password);
    }
}
```

Also, yes `gets` is deprecated. Use `fgets` as I did above.

EDIT (To answer the comment questions):

1. As per manual:

   `char* gets(char *s)`: `gets()  reads  a  line  from stdin into the buffer pointed to by s until either a terminating newline or EOF, which it replaces with a null byte ('\0').  No check for buffer overrun is performed. Never use gets(). Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the  data  in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely  dangerous  to  use. It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead.`

   `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream)`: `fgets()  reads  in  at  most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an EOF or  a  newline. If  a  newline  is  read,  it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.`
2. I am referring to `sizeof(ans)` because `strcmp` will continue comparing until it encounters the null character. Therefore, inside `password` we only want to write up to the size of `ans`, and then fill the end with the null character. What you can also do is change this to use `strncmp` which does a comparison up to `n` bytes. In that case, you don't have to tell `fgets` to read in up to `sizeof(ans)` bytes.

Comment: Okay and You answered my real question and that is what the main difference between gets() and fgets() that casues the error statement that i get when i use gets()? @wyas

Comment: Yes and my problem entering the password was in the ans[]= Zanderg!. i had that exclamation mark and i didnt realize it was there. @wyas

Comment: One more question for you...and that is why when you use fgets(password) are your then referring to the sizeof the ans? @wyas